# I lose focus from the main page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a window that is not in my domain and I can not do to maintain the focus on my window. This is the code.
The work is only for IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    var win = window;

    var myOptions = "width=300,height=250,top=300px,left=300px,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=0";
    var myWinReplace = true;
    var myWinName = "xwin";
    var myUrl = "http://www.google.com";
    var myOpen = window.open(myUrl, myWinName , myOptions, myWinReplace);

    window.focus(); //option 1

    $(myOpen).load(function(){

        window.focus(); //option 2
        win.focus(); //option 3
        setTimeout(function() { window.focus(); }, 500); //option 4
        setTimeout(function() { win.focus(); }, 1500); //option 5

    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in this case, I have to view the data in the new window, so I go writing data to the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
myOpen.opener.focus();
```

Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_win_opener.asp) for more information